# Uninitialized Constant ConfirmationEmailWorker::Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am having an issue launching sidekiq from the CLI. The current Error is:

```
   `uninitialized constant ConfirmationEmailWorker::SideKiq
    /Users/alexfroelich/Desktop/project/app/workers/confirmation_email_worker.rb:2:in `<class:ConfirmationEmailWorker>'
    /Users/alexfroelich/Desktop/project/app/workers/confirmation_email_worker.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:213:in `boot_system'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:42:in `parse'
    /Users/alexfroelich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

My `config/application.rb` looks like the following as I was reading that eager_loading, auto_loading might do the trick (although it seems repetitive as rails loads everything in `app/`)

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    console do 
        require 'pry'
        config.console = Pry
    end

    config.generators do |g|
        g.stylesheets false
        g.migration false
        g.javascripts false
        g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: false
        g.template_engine false
    end

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)

 config.before_configuration do
    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'mailer.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end


    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Located in the `app/workers` folder i have the following file `confirmation_email_worker.rb`

```
class ConfirmationEmailWorker
    include SideKiq::Worker

        def perform
            DairyMailer.order_confirmation.deliver
        end
end
```

Pretty stumped on this one..So any guidance is welcomed! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sidekiq` is all one word, lowercase.

Remove the capital letters.

```
include Sidekiq::Worker
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this:

```
class ConfirmationEmailWorker
 include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
        DairyMailer.order_confirmation.deliver
    end
end
```

Change `SideKiq::Worker` to `Sidekiq::Worker`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
class ConfirmationEmailWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
       DairyMailer.delay.order_confirmation.deliver
    end
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No such luck :( Thanks for taking a look though

Comment: Have you set up DairyMailer properly? Also the method `order_confirmation`.